# How to create directories based in a text file and move files to the new created directories

Tags: bash

I have a file text with names of files like this:

```
 file1.txt
 PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Pancreas_inweb3.txt.0.solution
 PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.3.Combined.inweb3.Pancreas_inweb3.txt.0.solution
 PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Arteria_inweb3.txt.0.solution
 PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.3.Combined.inweb3.Arteria_inweb3.txt.0.solution
 PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Adipose_inweb3.txt.0.solution
```

What I want is created new directories based on the unique names after `Combined.inweb3` and before `_inweb3.txt.0.solution`, and then move the files with the unique names to the new directories, here is a descriptive idea from what I want to achieve

```
# Create directories
mkdir Pancreas
mkdir Arteria
mkdir Adipose

# Move files to new directories
mv *.Pancreas_*.solution Pancreas/
mv *.Arteria_*.solution Arteria/
mv *.Adipose_*.solution Adipose/
```

So far I am using `grep` and `mv` but I have a lot of files and take a bit of time

Comment: Sounds like a question good for http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A little `bash` script like this should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f; do
   # Get the directory name and make it
   d=$(sed -e 's/_inweb3.*//' -e 's/.*inweb3.//' <<< "$f")
   echo Directory: $d
   mkdir -p "$d"
   echo cp "$f" "$d"
done < file1
```

**Sample Output**

```
Directory: Pancreas
cp PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Pancreas_inweb3.txt.0.solution Pancreas
Directory: Pancreas
cp PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.3.Combined.inweb3.Pancreas_inweb3.txt.0.solution Pancreas
Directory: Arteria
cp PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Arteria_inweb3.txt.0.solution Arteria
Directory: Arteria
cp PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.3.Combined.inweb3.Arteria_inweb3.txt.0.solution Arteria
Directory: Adipose
cp PCSTW.ABO.8.inv.term.2.Combined.inweb3.Adipose_inweb3.txt.0.solution Adipose
```